# Specific editing unity 7.1.2 launcher, the padding space of the icons

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

In 13.10   Unity, how can I edit the space between the icon itself and the padding enabled by default?

[image: screenshot]  **In dconf** the icon size is editable.

The area from the icon to the 'white' of the editor window.

I assume it's some function that adjusts the padding when you resize, I'd just set it to zero.

I know this a bit much , but I figure if anyone would know how do this it'd be someone on here.

Answer (score 0):

I found something I thought was it... in /usr/share/unity/themes  called

"dash-widgets.json"

which had padding variables in there, but was not pertaining to the right thing.
Maybe this clarifies what I'm looking for in the original question.

here are some pics to clarify what I mean too.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1cqZ.jpg